# Trying to sort posts by the number of likes mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, coffeescript

I'm trying to sort posts by the number of likes, using expressjs and mongodb.

```
   get "postsByLikes/:category", (req, res, next) ->
      category = req.params.category
      db.posts.aggregate([
        {$match:
          type: "post"
          category: category}
        {$project:
          likesCount:
            $size: "like"}
        {"$sort": 
          "likesCount": -1}
      ]).toArray (err, posts) ->

        res.send(posts)
```

What's wrong with this query?

Comment: How do we know? Please explain what you need

Comment: Did you miss the $ ? Should be `$size:"$like"`

Comment: @Veeram Thanks that was the problem! Feel free to post an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what's the output but based on your code it seems like you're getting only numbers without source documents. The reason for that is you use:

```
{$project:
      likesCount:
        $size: "like"}
```

to get the counts. The thing is that `$project` will return only specified fields (just `likesCount` in this case). To fix that you need [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) instead of `$project` to get source document and new calculated fields:

```
{$addFields:
      likesCount:
        $size: "$like"}
```